# DSNless connection for Aruna DB?

Tags: c#, .net, odbc, connection-string, dsn

Right now we are using Fastpath ODBC DSN connection method to access our ["ARUNA"](http://www.arunadb.com) Database. Our development platform is C# on the .NET Framework.

We are in need of connecting the DB without using DSN.

**Is it possible to connect Aruna using DSN less method?**

#### Update

Somewhere I heard about ODBC Bridge softwares, can anybody shed light on this whether it will be the kind of solution for my above problem?.

#### Update 2

We are now proposed with Webservice solution. Have the DSN, FastPath, DB and Webservice all deployed in the server. The webservice will take the request from the remote client and serve the data from the DB.

Are we heading in the right direction?

For this, we are in need of developing webservice application and also change all the code in the client tool to work with the webservice.

Is there any optimal solution?